# how to force chrome to use mesa software driver for webgl

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, webgl, mesa

I want to force chrome to render WebGL using software drivers, not hardware.

I'm using Ubuntu Linux and I understand that the Mesa GL drivers can be forced to use a software implementation by specifying the environment variable, [LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1](http://www.mesa3d.org/envvars.html), when launching a program. I confirmed that the driver changes when specifying the env var.

```
bash$ glxinfo | grep -i "opengl"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL extensions:

bash$ LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 glxinfo | grep -i "opengl"
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
```

The default GL driver provides OpenGL 1.4 support, and the software driver provides OpenGL 2.1 support.

I tracked down where the desktop launcher exists (/usr/share/applications/) and edited it to specify the env var, but chrome://gpu still shows GL version    1.4. The Chrome GPU info contains a promising value:

Command Line Args   --flag-switches-begin --disable-accelerated-2d-canvas --ignore-gpu-blacklist --flag-switches-end

I wonder if I can customize the --flag-switches-begin.

I also found the '--use-gl' [command line switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but I'm not sure how to leverage it to force the driver into software mode.

As a side note, I have already enabled 'Override software rendering list' in chrome://flags/, which did remove my model from the '[blacklist](http://borninbronx.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/chrome-on-linux-with-webgl-and-all-the-hardware-acceleration-stuff/#comment-55)' making it possible to use WebGL, but the OpenGL feature set is still quite limited.

I have an old laptop with a terrible 'gpu' that I would like to use to develop some shaders and test in WebGL, no matter the performance.

Is it possible to tell Chrome to use the software drivers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a linux box so I can't check but you can specify a prefix chrome will use for launching the GPU process with

```
--gpu-launcher=<prefix>
```

It's normally used for debugging for example

```
--gpu-launcher="xterm -e gdb --args"
```

When chrome launches a process it calls spawn. Normally it just launches

```
path/to/chrome <various flags>
```

`--gpu-launcher` lets you add a prefix to that. So for example

```
 --gpu-launcher=/usr/local/yourname/launch.sh
```

would make it spawn

```
 /usr/local/yourname/launch.sh path/to/chrome <various flags>
```

You can now make /usr/local/yourname/launch.sh do whatever you want and finally launch chrome. The simplest would be something like

```
#!/bin/sh
"$@"
```

In your case I'd guess you'd want

```
#!/bin/sh
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
"$@"
```

Be sure to mark `launch.sh` as executable.

---

given the script above this worked for me

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --ignore-gpu-blacklist --gpu-launcher=/usr/local/gman/launch.sh
```

after which `about:gpu` gives me

```
GL_VENDOR   VMware, Inc.
GL_RENDERER Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x301)
GL_VERSION  2.1 Mesa 9.0.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have since tried to use the flag you mention, but I am not sure what process I need to be launching. Simply specifying the env var, or xterm, leads to WebGL being disabled on chrome://gpu. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I'm very close. I did like you suggested, and I can see a difference. chrome://gpu now shows WebGL support when specifying the --gpu-launcher. However, chrome://gpu also shows the OpenGL version still at 1.4, when I was hoping to see OpenGL 2.1. Any ideas? Maybe 'export' is wrong? Maybe chrome does not use glx?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this works. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Is it possible to force one webgl context on a page to use software, while another one uses hardware?