# Is it possible to use puppeteer to pass a Javascript object to nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, tensorflow.js

## Background

I am using [Posenet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet) (see the in browser demo [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.html)) for keypoint detection. I have set it up to run on a WebRTC MediaStream, s.t.:

**Client:** Runs in a chrome tab on machine `A`. Initializes WebRTC connection and sends a MediaStream to **Server**. Receives back real time keypoint data from **Server** via WebRTC's DataChannel.

**Server:** Runs in a chrome tab on machine `B`, receives a WebRTC stream and passes the corresponding MediaStream to Posenet. Posenet does its thing and computes keypoints. This keypoint data is then send back to the **client** via WebRTC's DataChannel (if you have a better idea, I'm all ears).

**Problem:** I would like to have the server receive multiple streams from various clients and run Posenet on each, sending real time keypoint data to all clients. Though I'm not thrilled about the server utilizing Chrome, I am fine with using `puppeteer` and Chrome's headless mode for now, mainly to abstract away WebRTC's complexity.

## Approaches

I have tried two approaches, being heavily in favor of approach `#2`:

### Approach #1

Run `@tensorflow/tfjs` inside the `puppeteer` context (i.e. inside a headless chrome tab). However, I cannot seem to get the [PoseNet Browser Demo](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.html) working in headless mode, due to some WebGL error (it does work in non-headless mode though). I tried the following (passing `args` to `puppeteer.launch()` to enable WebGL, though I haven't had any luck - see [here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-puppeteerdefaultargsoptions) and [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) for reference):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--enable-webgl-draft-extensions', '--enable-webgl-image-chromium', '--enable-webgl-swap-chain', '--enable-webgl2-compute-context']
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.html', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
  });
  // Make chromium console calls available to nodejs console
  page.on('console', msg => {
    for (let i = 0; i < msg.args().length; ++i)
      console.log(`${i}: ${msg.args()[i]}`);
  });
}

main();
```

In headless mode, I am receiving this error message.

```sh
0: JSHandle:Initialization of backend webgl failed
0: JSHandle:Error: WebGL is not supported on this device
```

This leaves me with `question #1`: How do I enable WebGL in `puppeteer`?

### Approach #2

Preferably, I would like to run `posenet` using the `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` backend, to accelerate computation. Therefore, I would to link `puppeteer` and `@tensorflow/tfjs-node`, s.t.:

- The `puppeteer-chrome-tab` talks WebRTC with the **client**. It makes a Mediastream object available to `node`.
- `node` takes this MediaStream and passes it to `posenet`, (and thus `@tensorflow/tfjs-node`), where the machine learning magic happens. `node` then passes detected keypoints back to `puppeteer-chrome-tab` which uses its `RTCDataChannel` to communicate them back to **client**.

#### Problem

The problem is that I cannot seem to get access to `puppeteer`'s MediaStream object **within** `node`, to pass this object to `posenet`. I'm only getting access to [`JSHandles`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-class-jshandle) and [`ElementHandles`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-class-elementhandle). Is it possible to pass the *javascript object* associated with the handle to `node`?

Concretely, this error is thrown:

```sh
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: When running in node, pixels must be an HTMLCanvasElement like the one returned by the `canvas` npm package
    at NodeJSKernelBackend.fromPixels (/home/work/code/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/nodejs_kernel_backend.js:1464:19)
    at Engine.fromPixels (/home/work/code/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:749:29)
    at fromPixels_ (/home/work/code/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/browser.js:85:28)
    at Object.fromPixels (/home/work/code/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/operation.js:46:29)
    at toInputTensor (/home/work/code/node_modules/@tensorflow-models/posenet/dist/util.js:164:60)
    at /home/work/code/node_modules/@tensorflow-models/posenet/dist/util.js:198:27
    at /home/work/code/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:349:22
    at Engine.scopedRun (/home/work/code/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:359:23)
    at Engine.tidy (/home/work/code/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:348:21)
    at Object.tidy (/home/work/code/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/globals.js:164:28)
```

Logging the `pixels` argument that is passed to `NodeJSKernelBackend.prototype.fromPixels = function (pixels, numChannels) {..}`, it evaluates to an [ElementHandle](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-class-elementhandle). I am aware that I can access *serializable* properties of a Javascript object, using `puppeteer`'s [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args). However, if I were to pass the `CanvasRenderingContext2D`'s `imageData` (using the method `getImageData()` to `node` by calling `puppeteer.evaluate(..)`, this means stringifying an entire raw image and then reconstructing it in `node`'s context.

This leaves me with `question #2`: Is there any way to make an object from `puppeteer`'s context accessible (read-only) directly inside `node`, without having to go through e.g. `puppeteer.evaluate(..)`?

Comment: Anything you pass between node and browser context will be serialized due to the execution environmental differences. I did not find such a way since puppeteer was created.

Comment: Thanks for that insight. Do you have an idea about how to solve the WebGL error if I were to run tensorflowjs within the puppeteer context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend another approach with is to ditch the idea of using puppeteer on the server-side and instead implementing an actual WebRTC client in Node.js which then directly uses PoseNet via `@tensorflow/tfjs-node`.

### Why not to use puppeteer on the server-side

Using puppeteer on the server-side introduces a lot of complexity. On top of active WebRTC connections to multiple clients you now also have to manage one browser (or one tab at least) per connection. So, not only do you have to think about what happens when the connection to the clients fails, but you also have to prepare for other scenarios like browser crashes, page crashes, WebGL support (per page), document in the browser not loading, memory/CPU usage of the browser instances, ...

That said, let's go over your approaches.

**Approach 1: Running Tensorflow.js inside puppeteer**

You should be able to get this running by using only the `cpu` [backend](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#setBackend). You can set the backend like this before using any other code:

```js
tf.setBackend('cpu');
```

You might also be able to get WebGL running (as you are [not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48011613/5627599) having problems with WebGL and puppeteer). But even if you get it running, you are now running a Node.js script to start a Chrome browser that starts a WebRTC session and Tensorflow.js training inside a website. Complexity-wise, this will be *very* hard to debug if any problems occur...

**Approach 2: Transferring the data between puppeteer and Node.js**

This approach will be nearly impossible without a large slowdown (regarding the sending and receiving of frames). puppeteer needs to serialize any exchanged data. There is no such thing as shared memory or shared data objects between the Node.js and the browser environment. This means you would have to serialize each frame (all the pixels...) to transfer them from the browser environment to Node.js. Performance-wise, this might work okay for small images, but will become worse the bigger your images are.

---

All in all, you are introducing a lot of complexity if you want to go with one of your two approaches. Therefore, let's look at the alternative.

### Alternative approach: Send your video stream directly to your server

Instead of using puppeteer to establish a WebRTC connection, you can directly implement a WebRTC peer. I read form your question that you fear the complexity, but it is probably worth the hassle.

To implement a WebRTC server, you can use the library [`node-webrtc`](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc), which allows to implement a WebRTC peer on the server-side. There are multiple examples, of which one is very interesting for your use case. This is the [`video-compositing`](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc-examples/tree/master/examples/video-compositing) example, which establishes a connection between client (browser) and server (Node.js) to stream a video. Then the server will modify the sent frames and put a "watermark" on top of them.

**Code Sample**

The following code shows the most relevant lines from the [`video-compositing`](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc-examples/blob/master/examples/video-compositing/server.js) example. The code reads a frame from the input stream and creates a [`node-canvas`](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) object from it.

```js
const lastFrameCanvas = createCanvas(lastFrame.width,  lastFrame.height);
const lastFrameContext = lastFrameCanvas.getContext('2d', { pixelFormat: 'RGBA24' });

const rgba = new Uint8ClampedArray(lastFrame.width *  lastFrame.height * 4);
const rgbaFrame = createImageData(rgba, lastFrame.width, lastFrame.height);
i420ToRgba(lastFrame, rgbaFrame);

lastFrameContext.putImageData(rgbaFrame, 0, 0);
context.drawImage(lastFrameCanvas, 0, 0);
```

You now have a canvas object, which you can use the feed into the PoseNet like this:

```js
const net = await posenet.load();

// ...
const input = tf.browser.fromPixels(lastFrameCanvas);
const pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(input, /* ... */);
```

The resulting data now needs to be transferred back to the client which can be done by using a data channel. There is also an example ([`ping-pong`](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc-examples/tree/master/examples/ping-pong)) in the repository regarding that, which is much simpler than the video example.

Although you might fear the complexity of using `node-webrtc`, I recommend giving this approach and [`node-webrtc-examples`](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc-examples) a try. You can check out the repository first. All examples are ready to try and play around with.

Comment: Great answer, weighing pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those insights! Even though I'm only prototyping atm, I can now see how using puppeteer overcomplicates things. I'll go with `node-webrtc` or `simple-peer` and post results at some stage. Using `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` really seems like the only solution.

Comment: @Sean Glad I could help. Be aware, that `simple-peer` only supports data channels when used with Node.js ([more information](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer/issues/291#issuecomment-382838222)).

Comment: @ThomasDondorf Oh thanks, that's a really helpful heads-up, I was about to head in the wrong direction again.. `node-webrtc` it is - now I see what the `RTCVideoSink` is all about.

Comment: For anybody wondering how this ended up: I managed to build what I need using `node-webrtc` and the `RTCVideoSink` as proposed by @ThomasDondorf. I wrote a custom signaling server for `WebRTC` that handles connections and spawns nodejs worker threads. Only problem that remains is to get node's `canvas` library context aware - right now it doesn't support multiple worker threads. There is some discussion going on atm: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1394

Comment: I am late to the party but facing similar overall problem of streaming to server and doing 3D pose estimation real-time. Do you have any sample code to share how you achieved real-time streaming with `node-webrtc`? Would be super helpful!
Also did you find an approach to make it working with Python as most of SOTA deep learning is in Pytorch or TF Python API.

Comment: Hey @AnuarY Unfortunately the code is quite messy and contains certificate data, which is why it is private as ow now. DM me if you require any concrete info and I'll gladly share it with you :) it was js/ts only, no python.

Comment: No problem, I figured out an alternative and much simpler method for my simple application by just sending stream through a websocket.