# Unity3D WebGL Headless not rendering

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, chromium, headless, unity-webgl

I have posted the [same question](https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-headless-screenshots-not-rendering-properly.868042/) over Unity's forum, but there hasn't been any answer and thus posting it here, too.

I have been trying to run a Unity **WebGL** build in **headless mode** (through puppeteer) while saving 'screenshots' of the game, but the camera rendering doesn't seem to be working. **The resulting images are all black**.

It **works** as expected when **not in headless mode** (but still **WebGL**).
It also **works** properly in **standalone builds** (e.g., windows, mac), through **-batchMode**.

Here's the code in question:

```
// Problem seems to be in the following 2 lines
RenderTexture.active = camera.targetTexture;
camera.Render();

// same dimensions, both in headless and not headless
Debug.Log("CAMERA TARGET TEXTURE WIDTH: " + camera.targetTexture.width);
Debug.Log("CAMERA TARGET TEXTURE HEIGHT: " + camera.targetTexture.height);

tempTexture2D = new Texture2D(camera.targetTexture.width, camera.targetTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
tempTexture2D.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, camera.targetTexture.width, camera.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);
tempTexture2D.Apply();

// RGBA(0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000): totally black, when in WebGL headless mode. Works fine otherwise.
Debug.Log(tempTexture2D.GetPixels(100, 100, 1, 1)[0].ToString());

// Encode texture into JPG
byte[] bytes = tempTexture2D.EncodeToJPG();

// byte count is almost half when in headless mode
Debug.Log("IMG " + frameNumber + " byte count: " + bytes.Length);
// save to persistentData (indexedDB in WebGL)
// that data is then read on client side and encoded again
```

I found some differences between the Webgl headfull and headless versions (respective pictures below).
[image: headfull gpu stats]
[image: headless gpu stats]

I have also tried to set `--use-gl=swiftshader` which has better gpu stats, but still shows everything in black:
[image: headless swift shader gpu stats]

To be clear, the arguments I'm passing to chromium are the following:

```
args:[
 '--headless',
 '--hide-scrollbars',
 '--mute-audio',
 '--no-sandbox',
 '--use-gl=swiftshader' // tested with and without
]
```

The **headless log output** coming from unity is the following:

```
PAGE LOG: Loading player data from data.unity3d
PAGE LOG: Initialize engine version: 2018.4.10f1 (a0470569e97b)
PAGE LOG: Creating WebGL 2.0 context.
PAGE LOG: Renderer: WebKit WebGL
PAGE LOG: Vendor: WebKit
PAGE LOG: Version: OpenGL ES 3.0 (WebGL 2.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 Chromium))
PAGE LOG: GLES: 3
PAGE LOG: EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_float EXT_float_blend GL_EXT_float_blend EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_float_linear WEBGL_compressed_texture_etc GL_WEBGL_compressed_texture_etc WEBGL_compressed_texture_etc1 GL_WEBGL_compressed_texture_etc1 WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc GL_WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc WEBGL_debug_renderer_info GL_WEBGL_debug_renderer_info WEBGL_debug_shaders GL_WEBGL_debug_shaders WEBGL_lose_context GL_WEBGL_lose_context
PAGE LOG: OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 3.0 graphics device ; Context level <OpenGL ES 3.0> ; Context handle 1
PAGE LOG: UnloadTime: 0.340000 ms
PAGE LOG: [.WebGL-0x7fcdb69e1600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glFramebufferTexture2D: <- error from previous GL command
PAGE LOG: [.WebGL-0x7fcdb69e1600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GetShaderiv: <- error from previous GL command
PAGE LOG: WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: renderbufferStorageMultisample: samples out of range
PAGE LOG: [.WebGL-0x7fcdb69e1600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
PAGE LOG: [.WebGL-0x7fcdb69e1600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
PAGE LOG: [.WebGL-0x7fcdb69e1600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: framebuffer incomplete
PAGE LOG: [.WebGL-0x7fcdb69e1600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glBlitFramebufferCHROMIUM: framebuffer incomplete
```

Could the problem be the WebGL hardware acceleration altogether? Can I disable it from my WebGL build?

This issue seems to be related with: [Rendering WebGL image in headless chrome without a GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011613/rendering-webgl-image-in-headless-chrome-without-a-gpu?rq=1)

But that seems to be working properly, at least under MacOS:
https://github.com/Apidcloud/WebGLHeadlessRendering

So I'm still assuming it has something to do with Unity3D. Even if **headfull**, it will become **black** when using `swift shader`, with the only gpu stats difference being **video decode--hardware acceleration disabled**:
[image: headfull swift shader gpu stats]

Thanks!

**Edit with answer** (more details on the actual answer below):

It finally works by disabling the **anti-aliasing** in **unity**, which seems to throw some OpenGL errors. Works with and without `swift shader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 or 3 days struggling with this and trying to find the exact problem, it finally works by disabling the anti-aliasing in unity, which seems to throw some OpenGL errors.

That said, the Unity3D WebGL rendering **works headlessly** (through chromium and puppeteer) even without `swift shader`, though that is probably what you want for `no-gpu` scenarios (e.g., some server).

The log output, though still weird, for both scenarios (with and without `swift shader`) is the following (**note that the *framebuffer incomplete* errors are gone**):

```
PAGE LOG: [.WebGL-0x7f842a0f6400]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glFramebufferTexture2D: <- error from previous GL command
PAGE LOG: [.WebGL-0x7f842a0f6400]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GetShaderiv: <- error from previous GL command
```

Thanks!